# links on sharepoint site that point to ms files sitting on seperate file share

Tags: 2010, ms-project

There are a number of links on various pages on my site. These all point to MS Project files sitting on a separate file share.
Instead of opening the MS project programme itself its trying to open it in a new tab in internet explorer.

Is this there a setting within SharePoint or MS Project that will apply this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a browser or computer setting. What happens when you open the file directly on the file share? If it's opening as expected, you may need to tell IE to ignore that file from opening. I don't believe this is feasible via the link in SharePoint. SharePoint after all is a web page, providing an HTML Link to a file, not much more to it.

Answer (score 0):

First check with other browsers too if you have the same issue. Sometimes it depends on the Office version you have installed.